# Use case for multiple login option

Tags: uml, use-case

I have a use case where user may log in via normal login, as well as social login such as Twitter, Google, Facebook. I draw the use case as below but not sure if it is correct.

Login account ---extends---> normal login 
              ---extends---> Twitter login 
              ---extends---> Google login 
              ---extends---> Facebook login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<<extends>>` works vice versa.

I'm quite tired telling this all the time, but `Login account` is not a use case. It does not deliver any value to an actor. It is a simple constraint which applies to other *real* use cases.

Further: avoid the use of `<<extends>>`/`<<include>>`. They are a sign of functional analysis you are trying to do with your use cases. Instead use cases are synthesized which makes a big difference. If your use case diagrams start resembling a spider's web your design is broken.

Recommended read: Bittner/Spence.

Comment: if login account is not a use case, so do create account, forgot password feature and login process?

Comment: `Create account` is a use case since in the end you have created something new. `Retrieve lost password` is also a use case. `Process login` is a technical use case you find when you model your system internals. But from outside `login to account` is not a use case but a constraint. Modeling use cases is not a trivial task and I've seen more wrong than right use case models.

Answer (score 4):

In general I tend to agree with Thomas Kilian to be careful with use cases for loggin in as they generally do not pass the **boss test**.

> Will my boss be happy if I do [--insert use case--] 100 times?

But use cases are used in many different ways, and for many different systems. If your system is authentication service then I guess **Log In** might be an important use case.

Anyhow, the extend relations are pretty much wrong. 
There is also a heated debate in the community on what extends really means, and how to use it. I usually advice not to use extend at all.
But if you want to keep them then you probably need to do it the other way around.

The extending use case inserts some specific functionality to the extended use case at a specific point in the execution of the extended use case (the extension point). The extended use case has no knowledge of the extending use case(s).

**Extends** is probably not what you need here.

I would probably not go into that much detail, and stick to the single **Log in** use case (if any). You could make alternate scenario's for facebook, twitter, google, etc...

But if you really need this much detail in your use case model then I would use **generalization**
[image]

As you can see there is one abstract use case **Log in**. The three other **concrete** use cases inherit from this use case.

In analyses there are no right or wrong answers. There are only better or worse answers, and it all depends heavily on the purpose of your model.

Comment: Using generalization with use cases is __very__ touchy. There is no good way in activities on how to describe where to override inheritance. This finally will make the flow of actions almost unreadable since you have to have place holders in the general use case which you replace in the  generalized use cases. And finally: `Log in` is not a use case at all: http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1430572914#4

Comment: Whenever I use inheritance in use cases I usually don't describe the scenario's in the abstract use case but leave that to the concrete sub-use cases. Only those abstract  things that are true for all sub-use cases get described in the abstract use case

Answer (score 1):

I think your use cases are a little too technical. When you're identifying use cases, you need to go back over them a few times to make sure the complete set of uses cases is meaningful. This often means some use cases are merged into a single one, others are split, etc.

The key question to ask when differentiating use cases is "is the difference between these two use cases meaningful to the actor?" You should not be asking "are there different ways to achieve this functionality?" or "will the implementation need to support several different protocols?" These are design issues, which should be documented not in the use cases but in the collaborations which realize them. Realizing one use case with several different alternative collaborations is perfectly valid and normal use of UML.

In this case, does it matter to the user *how* they log in or is it only important *that* they log in? I suspect the latter, in which case there should only be one use case.