# Which arrows should be in relation between registration and login?

Tags: java, uml

[image: UML diagram with USER]

Which arrows should be in relation between registration and login? After register or recovery password user can go to login. In my diagram should be arrows between register/recovery to login? If yes, which? Arrows directed to or from a login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use case for multiple login option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013734/use-case-for-multiple-login-option)

Comment: FWIW: Manage is not a use case (like so many manages are just useless). If it were some use case, your dependency is neither stereotyped include not extend. If it were, I'd start arguing that you should simply avoid its use since it's a sign of functional decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no relationships between register/recovery and login.
Use cases diagrams are not used to show these kinds of dependencies.

Also
http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case.html#association
states "Two use cases specifying the same subject cannot be associated since each of them individually describes a complete usage of the system."