# include & LogIn in UML use case

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case, magic-draw

I have an account based system,it means that every feature of the system can be used only after Log In.Also,as far as I know in use case diagrams we 'include' something in the base case if it is meaningless without the included action.Back to my problem,I have to draw the use case diagram of the system mentioned above and since every feature of the system can be used after login do I have to 'include' LogIn in every use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use case for multiple login option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013734/use-case-for-multiple-login-option)

Answer (score 4):

No. It is common practice to define "The user is logged in" as a postcondition for use case "Log in" and as a precondition for the other use cases.

In the use case community, people disagree on whether "Log in" should be a use case at all. According to UML, every use case must yield an observable result that is of value for actors or other stakeholders. A use case like "Log in" does not satisfy this requirement, in my view. Still, this use case is a useful way to describe the system's behavior during the log in process, so I would just keep your "Log in" use case.