# Should extend always be be written in a Use Case Scenario?

Tags: uml, use-case, scenarios, use-case-diagram

In this example I have a main Login use case which will call the use case, "Account Verification". In this scenario, I feel Register would need to be detailed in a Use Case Scenario document but would Account Verification, Login Error: Account Authentication Failed & Log User Activity require a Use Case Scenario to be written since these are not use cases the User would directly interact with?

[image]

Comment: THat's a traditional debate in this community: Login is not a use case:  it's no added value for the user, just a constraint for using the system.  I'll not answer this founded questing, since a lot of other answers explain this with more or less details),  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53907281/3723423 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651397/include-login-in-uml-use-case.  The UCD is not a flow diagram that shows the flow of activities in the sytem.  If you want to model flows, consider using activity diagrams.

Comment: (by the way,  congratulations for your hard work and in-depth studying of use cases -  a lot of interesting questions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and linking the other answers. Those do seem to clear things up a lot more! Thanks!